# NSDictionary inside NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, key, nsdictionary

Ok I have a .plist file,

In which I have an `NSDictionary *StoredAddresses`,

Inside `StoredAddresses`, is another handful of `NSDictionary`

I know I can use,

```
if ([dictionaryOfAddresses objectForKey:@"StoredAddresses"])
```

To access the top level NSDictionaries, but how can I search for keys inside the stored addresses?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, if I read this correctly, you have dictionaries within dictionaries. This works just like any other object:

```
NSDictionary* Address=[dictionaryOfAddresses objectForKey:@"Home Address"];
NSString* Street=[Address objectForKey:@"Street"];
```

You could combine the calls if you want to:

```
NSString* Street=[[dictionaryOfAddresses objectForKey:@"Home Address"] objectForKey:@"Street"];
```

Comment: thank you so much, and I assume I can add even a third layer into this ?

Comment: You can add as many "layers" as you want. The only thing that matters is that you know what object you are getting in each case. Strings and dictionaries aren't the only options, you could have arrays, dates or numbers too. Dictionaries are just "given a key, return the value associated with it". The dictionary doesn't care what kind of value is stored at a key.

Comment: Also with the modern Objective-C syntax, you can use dictionaryOfAddresses[@"Home Address"][@"Street"] instead. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `NSKeyValueCoding` method `valueForKeyPath:` to access properties of nested objects. For example, given the following dictionaries...

```
NSDictionary *homeAddressDict = @{ @"street" : @"2 Elm St.", @"city" : @"Reston" };
NSDictionary *addressesDict = @{ @"home" : homeAddressDict };
```

...you can access values of the nested `home` dictionary as follows:

```
NSString *street = [addressesDict valueForKeyPath:@"home.street"];
NSString *city = [addressesDict valueForKeyPath:@"home.city"];
```

This works the same for more deeply nested paths, for example:

```
NSDictionary *contactDict = @{ @"name" : @"Jim Ray", @"addresses" : addressesDict };

NSString *street2 = [contactDict valueForKeyPath:@"addresses.home.street"];
NSString *city2 = [contactDict valueForKeyPath:@"addresses.home.city"];
```

Note that this will work regardless of whether the objects are instances of `NSDictionary` or any custom class that descends from `NSObject`, provided that the custom class has properties or instance variables whose names match the keys.

So for example, instead of using an `NSDictionary` for home address, you could substitute an instance of a custom `Address` class that had declared properties, getter methods, or instance variables named **street** and **city** (or instance variables named **_street** and **_city**), and still access it the same way.

And if the object containing the target property is mutable (for example an instance of `NSMutableDictionary`), you can even modify the value using the same mechanism, for example:

```
[contactDict setValue:@"Herndon" forKeyPath:@"addresses.home.city"];
```

Answer (score 1):

THis will return the array of the keys inside **StoredAddresses**

```
yourArray=[[dictionaryOfAddresses objectForKey:@"StoredAddresses"] allKeys];
```

then you can print the yourArray and see the keys, then after knowing the keys you can access using either

```
dict=[[dictionaryOfAddresses objectForKey:@"StoredAddresses"] objectForKey:[yourArray objectAtIndex:index_for_that_key]];
```

or

```
dict=[[dictionaryOfAddresses objectForKey:@"StoredAddresses"] objectForKey:@"key_for_your_dict"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another new way of getting subdictionaries that makes some neat code is the following shorthand notation:

```
NSString *street = dictionaryOfAddresses[@"HomeAddress"][@"Street"];
```